# Can I linearize this piecewise function so it can be used in an objective function for my LP optimization model?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, non-convex-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

I am looking for methods to linearize this piecewise function so that it can be added to an optimization function of a linear programming problem. I figured out how to do this for mixed integer programming, but I would ideally be able to make it work with linear programming.

$$
\min f(x)
$$
When $0\leq x \leq b$
$$
f(x) = x - a  
$$
when $x > b$
$$
f(x) = b - a 
$$

$a$ and $b$ are constants. $x$ is the decision variable. I want to minimize $f(x)$. Can just plug in $a=4$, $b=10$, or something like that.

From what I have read online in blogs and papers, it seems like it would require a binary variable or an SOS set. I am using PuLP as my solver, which does not have SOS sets. Is it possible to linearize this function without having to use mixed integer programming?

Thank you!

Comment: Are there any constraints to the problem, besides $x\geq 0$? If there are not, isn't the minimum at $x=0$, with minimal value of $f(0) = -a$?

Comment: Yes, this is actually just a piece of an objective function to be added to a larger objective function with a large number of constraints. Just focusing on this part as it is the only piecewise part. Everything else is already worked out.

Comment: This can be linearized, however it may result in some instability in your optimization algorithm, since whenever $x$ goes through $b$ the derivative changes from $0$ to $1$, or from $1$ to $0$. Without context is hard to tell what would be the best approach, but one suggestion would be to use a soft-version of the function, which will have better numerical behavior: for example, we usually use sigmoid functions to replace hard step functions in artificial neural network models.

Comment: You could partition the domain so that $f$ is affine on each part, solve each separately and take the $\min$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your piecewise-linear function is concave and so cannot be linearized without introducing a binary variable. If it were instead convex, you could use linear programming.

Comment: Thanks for your time. A mentor of mine is telling me that it should be solvable using slack variables and/or Big M. I can't seem to get it, which would make sense given your comment hahaa. Is there a name for this rule/proof that shows this fact? Just curious so I can look into why. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Yes, a big-M formulation works, but that uses a binary variable.  A general result is that the feasible region for linear programming is convex, so if your solution space is not convex, there is no LP formulation.  Here, the nonconvexity is in the objective, so to apply this result, first reformulate with an "epigraph" approach: introduce a variable $z$ and minimize $z$ subject to $z \ge f(x)$.  Now your variables are $(x,z)$, and the feasible region is above the piecewise-linear function.  A simple plot shows the nonconvexity of this region.

Comment: Yes, I solved for BigM using binary variables & I solved using slack variables and an SOS set. Seems like that is the only way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "low-tech" way to handle this would be to break it up into two linear programming problems, one with $x-a$ and constraint $x \le b$, the other with $b-a$ and constraint $x \ge b$, and take whichever optimal solution has the lower objective value.  Of course, this doesn't scale well if you have lots of terms of this type.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion - I will consider it. This term is the only one with a piecewise function. The issue is that I just put _x_ in the above problem, but the actual problem is finding thousands of _xi_, and splitting all _xi_ into all combinations of _xi<b_ and _xi>b_ would square the compute needs. Given this, it would seem like a binary variable is a better solution, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant about "lots of terms".  Of course, having thousands of binary variables could also make things difficult.

Comment: Got it. Yes, thousands of binary variables would be necessary as well. Thank you!